# Type of pointer of array

Tags: c++, pointers

Below is the code

```
void printLoop(type?? p){

for(int i  = 0; i<2;i++)
{
   for(int e = 0;e<3;e++)
        {
             cout<<p[i][e]<<" ";
         }
      cout<<"\n";
  }
}
void array()
{
int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
int (*p)[3] = a;
printLoop(p);
}
```

Basic idea is that I want to print out the array using a for loop in the printLoop func. However, I need to know the type of that pointer which has the address of the 2D array. What's the pointer's type? Is it `int (*)[]`? I'm confused.

Also what does "`(*p)`" mean(from `int (*p)[3])` ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a really good read: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html. From this, working counterclockwise you can see `p` is a pointer `*` to an array `[]` of `3` `int`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does "(*p)" mean(from int (*p)[3]) ?

`p` is a pointer to an array of size `3` of objects of type `int`.

You have multiple possibilites for your `printLoop` function (though with the general C-restriction that you can leave at most one -- the outermost declarator empty):

- You can specify the dimensions explicitly:

  `void printLoop(int p[ 2 ][ 3 ]);`

The only advantage with this method is that the implementation *can* consider that the array being passed is of the desired size (i.e. 2x3 matrix of `int`s) as a pre-condition.

- You can leave out the [ 2 ] part entirely:

  `void printLoop(int p[][ 3 ]);`

or,

```
void printLoop(int (*p)[ 3 ]);
```

- You can use a pointer to a pointer of `int`

You will also need to pass the dimensions (if you skip one that is) along to make sure that you don't access out-of-bounds memory. So, your function signature should go like this:

```
void printLoop(int (*p)[ 3 ], int dim);
```

Comment: The first dimension will be lost either way, whether you define it or not. The array to pointer decay kicks in in function arguments as well.

Comment: @K-ballo: Yes. But the signature works as a *sort of documentation* for the implementer to take liberties.

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I have a better understanding of what's going on!

Answer (score 3):

For the `printLoop` function, `int p[2][3]` as an argument should just work.

```
int (*p)[3] = a;
```

`p` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s, initialized to point to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code is not very modern C++. It's basically "**c with iostreams**".

Second of all, `printLoop(int p[2][3])` is the signature you're looking for even though again, it's not the best way of doing things at all.

Third of all, `int (*p)[3]` is analyzed as follows: Start at the name which is `p` and take a look around (first to the right and then to the left yet here it doesn't matter) until you "hit" braces. There's only a star at it, so you can say that **p is a pointer**. Now you recursively do the same analysis again, you see `[3]`, which means that `p` is a pointer to an array that has 3 `int`s.

Now I'd like to mention the following:

Use `std::array` for staticly-sized arrays.
Use `std::vector` for dynamicaly-sized arrays.

Oh, also, I myself wouldn't use a 2D array, they are clunky and just a syntactic sugar (around the basic "array" notion which is a syntactic sugar as well).

So perhaps, something like this, brain compiled, hopefully correct, C++11 abusing:

```
std::array<int, 3 * 2> p = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};
std::for_each(std::begin(p), std::end(p), [](int elem){ std::cout<<elem; });
```

Nice and dandy. You could also have lambda check for some "2d array" sizes and insert newlines if you so desire.